# Find all open sets on $X=\{a,b\}$ with topology $\mathcal{T}_X=\{\emptyset,\{a\},X\}$

Tags: general-topology

I am currently working on a exercise about the product topology, which goes as follows:

Let $X=\{a,b\}$ and define a topology $\mathcal{T}_X=\{\emptyset,\{a\},X\}$ on it.

Now I need to determine all open sets in the product topology $X\times X$. This is what I have so far: a basis for the product topology is the following set:
$\{U_\alpha\times U_\beta\subset X\times X:U_\alpha,U_\beta\in \mathcal{T}_X\}$. In this case, this is equal to $\{\emptyset, X\times X, (a,a), X\times \{a\}, \{a\}\times X\}$. To find all the open sets, we have to take unions of elements in the basis, but since the unions are already in the basis, the elements of the basis are the open sets of the product topology. Is this correct?

Is it true that $X\times \emptyset$ is just the empty set?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $X\times \emptyset=\emptyset.$ Any member of $X\times Y$ is $(u,v)$ for some $u\in X, v\in Y.$ If $Y=\emptyset$ then there is no $v\in Y$ and hence no $(u,v).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(X\times \{a\})\cup (\{a\}\times X)$ is not in that collection. It is the complement of $\{(b,b)\}$, i.e., $\{(a,b),(b,a),(a,a)\}$.

Comment: I thought that $(X\times\{a\}) \cup (\{a\} \times X)$ would result in $X\times X$, I don't understand why this not true @geetha290krm

Comment: @Sam $(b,b) \notin (X\times\{a\})\cup(\{a\}\times X)$.